# Moving mouse creates KeyPress events, preventing holding down keys

Tags: drivers, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, shortcut-keys

On ubuntu 22.04LTS, when moving a `Lenovo Y Precision Gaming mouse`, I noticed it would prevent me from holding down a key, but not writing in several keystrokes

After some headaches I noticed that, while another mouse and the standard touchpad do not do this, my mouse creates a `KeyPress event` in `xev` for `key 248` (bound to nothing in `xmodmap`) by just moving it normally. That mouse and the touchpad do not have this issue.

Unfortunately I can't test this in another distribution, and `xinput` does not even reveal the option `"libinput Disable While Typing Enabled"` (even though the behavior of this being enabled anyway would not be to prevent me from holding down a key)

Would appreciate any help, since I can't figure out if it is an unfixable problem with my mouse, which only has windows drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with `xinput set-prop keyboard:"Lenovo Lenovo Y Gaming Precision Mouse" "Device Enabled" 0 on my .xsessionrc file`, my mouse for some reason was listed as both pointer and keyboard